# How to use a proper software to read an old-version Mathematica code better?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm using Mathematica 10 now, however, when I read/use codes written in an old-version, for instance, 2002, some codes may change heavily.

Can anyone recommend a good software to read them? I tried sublime text 3, but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: mathematica.stackexchange.com but give some example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the old code in a Mathematica Notebook (`.nb`) file? If so, then you should be able to open it in Mathematica 10. It may just prompt you while you are opening it, saying something like, "*This notebook was created in an older version of Mathematica, some things might be weird.*"